# Regarding adding the statements at console

Tags: java

I have developed a Java program that will count the number of files in the folder. There may be Java files or text files, of which it will count the number of lines of code. The idea is to print the file name to the console, followed by the line count. This part is done, shown below:

```
public class FileCountLine {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        File directory = new File("C:/Test/");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                }
            }}
        for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:result.entrySet()){
              System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" ==> "+entry.getValue());
            }       
    }}
```

Right now I have hard coded the location of the directory like this:

```
File directory = new File("C:/Test/");
```

I want this to be more interactive, and prompt the user to enter the location into console. After the user presses Enter, it will do the rest of the functionality as is.

Comment: Is this homework? (Odd time of the year for it but who knows.)

Comment: Also: you're allowed to use more than one sentence in a paragraph.

Comment: Read this: [I/O from the Command Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.out.println() to output a prompt to the console screen. Then, to get their path, use the Scanner class in java.util eg,

```
Scanner lineIn = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = lineIn.next();
```

That string, input, can be your folder path but you probably want to do some error checking on the input for the correct format, good characters, etc

Answer (score 2):

why make it interactive?  why not just use the `args[]` parameter that main is given?

check args[0] to ensure it is a valid directory, then move on with life.

```
File directory = new File(args[0]);
```

or better yet, you could iterate over all of the elements of args and perform your check on every directory specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user for the drive and the main folder ..

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the Drive name like C,D,E etc");
String drive=in.next();
System.out.println("Enter the main folder name");
String main_folder=in.next();
File directory=new File(drive+":"+"//"+main_folder+"//");
```